# How to understand this piece of code in standard ML of NJ

Tags: syntax, sml

I have this code:

```
exception BadToken of string*(string list)
fun 
advance ts = let val h = hd (!ts)
                 val t = tl (!ts)
             in 
                 ts := t;
                 h
             end

fun
eat t ts = if (hd (!ts)) = t then (advance ts; t)
           else raise BadToken (t,!ts)
```

I don't understand what `:=`, `!` before ts and `;` stand for. In the interpreter, the datatype of advance is: `val advance = fn : 'a list ref -> 'a`

I don't understand what `'a list ref` means.

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin with `'a list ref`. `ref` is mutable data structure,so you can add and remove content to/from it, you can find description [here](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2008sp/recitations/rec15.html). `'a list ref` is `ref` data structure that contains list of any type. `:=` is overloaded operator for adding `t` to the content of `ts`, so after `ts := t` `ts` will contain `t`. `;` just separates statements or declarations, in your code you have 2 statements `ts := t` and `h`, so you need separate them with `;`. `!` is overloaded operator for getting content of `ref` object, so in your code it will return `'a list`.

Comment: Can a function in sml have more than one statement? I remember that it can only return one expression.

Comment: It can only return one expression, but `ts := t` will not return anything, since it's unit type, it cannot hold information.